# 'Must have' .NET components: experienced developers?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, components

I thought I'd canvas the more experienced .NET (mostly CSharp/ASP.NET) Developers on the most useful general components.  I've got about $5-$7k to spend as I want on components as part of a project which involves web based graphs/reports/data visualisation, but I want to get things that will be useful for general purpose the board while the cash is there to be had!  My current thoughts are as follows, any opinions welcome:

- Dundas Chart (already bought, I've had great experiences using it)
- Telerik .NET
- DevExpress DXperience (a bit of a dupe against the Telerik components but I figure if one has a strange bug or limitation you have the other as a fallback).  Both seem very comprehensive.
- Was considering a diagram type control like godiagram- it doesn't look visually amazing like the old Corgent/Dundas diagram did, but I can't find a better one presently.  If anyone knows a nice one that does anti-aliasing and suits workflow type diagrams, let me know!
- Considering a Telerik SiteFinity license, it looks quite good but not sure how well it'll combine with non-cms type pages, so the jury is out.

Any glaring omissions?  Thanks all!

Comment: "my really great components.com" ;-)

Comment: this is awesome http://www.antiyes.com/product/antiyes-image-resizer ... (shameless plug of my image resizer)

Comment: you might want to change the title so it is based around the body of your question: asp.net graph/report components.

Comment: Glinkot - thanks for choosing my answer as "the" answer.  Tools are so incredibly important that I spend a lot of time making sure that I get the right ones so I'm glad my experiences will help you.  BTW - I was attracted to Telerik's controls due to their Ajax integration as well.  What I found, though, was that it was very easy to wrap the DevExpress tools as well.  For example, I have a report parameters header where users can change stuff and update reports via Ajax and an auto-postback on the HTML editor.  Both were easy and worked quite well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have purchased the DevExpress and Telerik libraries and, while both are good, I ended up removing Telerik altogether and sticking with DevExpress for some pretty concrete reasons.

First, there *is* a great deal of overlap between the two and the two of them really share the leadership position in the ASP.NET/C# market.

DevExpress has a significant advantage with respect to their reporting tool.  No tool I evaluated was perfect (I looked at four altogether) but DevExpress was the easiest to get going with, the easiest to deploy and at least as powerful as any of the others (with the possible exception of the MS tool - but that has its own deployment problems).  This was a *big* advantage as reporting is central to my app as well.

The DevExpress charting library is *very* nice and integrates well with the reporting tool - another win for them.  Dundas and Telerik have nice libraries as well but, after *years* of doing charts, ease of setup/definition is important to me and DevExpress has the edge there.

Telerik has a better online HTML editor (we feature a CMS in our product) but the DevExpress product wasn't that far behind.  If I was not doing reporting/charting, I might go with Telerik on this basis alone since our CMS is quite important but it isn't enough of an advantage if you *are* doing reporting/charting.

The Grid products from both are great but DevExpress also offers a PivotGrid that is a spectacular data analysis tool and a nice addition to any site where data analysis is important.

Both have very good support in my experience.

The generic controls from both are very capable but, honestly, there's little reason to choose either one over the other for the controls that *I* care about.  My focus was on date-handling controls and numerical inputs.

So, I can absolutely see people being happy with either of the two but I ended up (after using both for about two years) going with just DevExpress.  It didn't hurt that the DevExpress team also wrote a book that really helped flesh out the range of uses to which their library could be put.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Heh, you're the 2nd person who I voted up by +10 to give 10k. Weird.

Comment: Heh - *THANKS* codekaizen - I've been looking forward to getting to 10K for some strange reason.  BTW - with only a handful of people at 10K+, what are the chances of you getting *two* of them to exactly 10K?

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Good to hear from someone who's used both.  I do like the telerik ajax controls which take care of the plumbing to avoid postbacks with a drag and drop type approach.  I'm still struggling to find a grid I really like.

Answer (score 7):

Before spending money on controls you might use, you should figure out what you're doing and buy the ones you will use.

I like the asp.net chart controls, http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2008/11/25/getting-started-with-the-asp-net-3-5-chart-control.aspx

but they're free.

Answer (score 2):

I completely agree with @John Boker, but would also add that you consider broadening your search to include development tools which might make your team faster at code production/testing/validation.

Making your code easier to build and maintain wins out over having a wide variety of expensive component libraries in my experience, and this is mostly due to having very good free versions of the controls you are looking for, yet a relative dearth of decent free code production tools.

Comment: Resharper or CodeRush are great for refactoring; Red Gate ANTS profilers are awesome for finding memory leaks and bottlenecks (and their SQL tools are slick as well); NDepend is great for analyzing large projects, Altova offers some slick XML/XSD tools.......

Comment: @Yoooder, those were just the ones I was thinking of, except dotTrace (http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/) for the profiler. Also I love SciTech's MemProfiler: http://www.memprofiler.com/.

Answer (score 2):

Development tools like ReSharper and dotTrace will be useful in writing efficient & maintainable code

Answer (score 0):

I think [Peter Blum's](http://www.peterblum.com)  validator controls are great, and his data entry stuff is pretty nice too.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server reporting services (if you're using SQL Server) might help you lose the cost of a few of these. Also the no frills [Google Chart API](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/) is cheap and a lot easier to integrate.